# PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run `rake db:migrate` but I encounter this error:

> PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted,
> commands ignored until end of transaction block
> /20150526112018_rename_inquiries_to_mandates.rb:15:in `change' /Users/alirezanobakht/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/bin/bundle:23:in` load'
> /Users/alirezanobakht/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/bin/bundle:23:in `'

also, my code in the migration file is:

```
 rename_column :company_inquiries, :inquiry_id, :mandate_id
 add_index :company_inquiries, :mandate_id rescue nil    
 create_join_table :companies, :mandates do |t|
          t.index [:company_id, :mandate_id]
          t.index [:mandate_id, :company_id]
     end
```

**note:** I got this error after updating my Rails version to 6.1, and maybe the reason is to write "add_index" just after "rename_column"

Comment: could you include _all_ the code in your migration file? some of it appears to be missing

Answer (score 1):

It *seems* to be because of this `rescue nil` after `add_index`. You have flow like that:

- Migration begins the transaction
- `rename_column` - executes some SQL - OK
- `add_index` - fails for some reason and raises an exception, it should abort the migration, but you're rescuing and ignoring the exception, so it just proceeds
- `create_join_table` - it tries to execute the SQL statement, but your transaction was already broken on the previous step, so it raises the `PG::InFailedSqlTransaction` exception

Not quite sure why exactly `add_index` fails, should work at a first glance, but try removing `rescue nil` and you should get the real error